# Nav bar cuts view on dismiss view controller on iPhone XS Max swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have two view controllers, VC1 and VC2, First I present VC1 and programmatically create Nav Bar and place two buttons in that, after that I present VC2 and the same I create navbar programmatically. Now when i dimiss VC2 to VC1 it cuts the view to half of navbar and button also get cutoff. I have tried different solutions but not getting it fixed. I'm confused why it is cutting the view? This is my code to create navbar in VC1,

```
let width = self.view.frame.width
    let navigationBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: width, height: 64))
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar);
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Owners")
    self.title = "Owners"
    let cancelBtn = UIButton()
    let searchBtn = UIButton()
    cancelBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "cancelBtn")?.tint(with: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)), for: .normal)
    cancelBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    cancelBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTapBack), for: .touchUpInside)
    let suggestButtonContainer = UIView(frame: cancelBtn.frame)
    suggestButtonContainer.addSubview(cancelBtn)
    searchBtn.setImage(Icon.cm.search?.tint(with: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)), for: .normal)
    searchBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    searchBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTapSearch), for: .touchUpInside)
    let searchView = UIView(frame: searchBtn.frame)
    searchView.addSubview(searchBtn)
    let searchButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchView)
    let suggestButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: suggestButtonContainer)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = suggestButtonItem
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchButtonItem
    navigationBar.setItems([navigationItem], animated: false)
```

and this is how i create VC2 navbar,

```
let width = self.view.frame.width
    let navigationBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 25, width: width, height: 64))
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar);
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem(title: "Owners")
    self.title = "Owners"
    let cancelBtn = UIButton()
    cancelBtn.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "cancelBtn")?.tint(with: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)), for: .normal)
    cancelBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    cancelBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTapBack), for: .touchUpInside)
    let suggestButtonContainer = UIView(frame: cancelBtn.frame)
    suggestButtonContainer.addSubview(cancelBtn)
    let suggestButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: suggestButtonContainer)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = suggestButtonItem
    navigationBar.setItems([navigationItem], animated: false)
```

Now when is dismiss from VC2 to VC1 it shows navbar like this,
[image]

Comment: Try to change y position of nav bar as VC2's nav bar let navigationBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 25, width: width, height: 64))

Comment: i have also tried with this but it shows same thing. @KishanBhatiya

Comment: Have you tried to change frame of navigation bar or layout subview when view will appear?

Comment: yes, but face same issue @KishanBhatiya

Comment: is nav bar only cut on iPhone XS Max device or any other device?

Comment: It cut off in all iPhone X, XS Max, Iphone 11 Pro, pro max but on Iphone 7,8,8 plus,6 it is running fine. @KishanBhatiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem come from the status bar height.

**20pt** for iPhone 6, 7, 8, ..., and **44pt** for iPhones with a notch.

try to set the navigation bar frame `origin.y` to `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height`

```
let navigationBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: width, height: 64))
```

Comment: Yes, your right this is due to status bar height, thank i have learned today a new thing :) . @Etienne Jézéquel